# How to print prediction by category inside a loop

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, conv-neural-network

I'm having a problem with printing pictures with labels of prediction in my project.

```
i = 1
for image in DATADIR:
    prediction = model.predict
    ([prepare(r'MY_DIR\manual_testing\{}.jpg'.format(i))])
    img = mpimg.imread(r'MY_DIR\manual_testing\{}.jpg'.format(i))
    imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
    print(CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0][0])])
    i += 1
```

Here `MY_DIR` replaces the actual directory.
I'm having the following error: `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

I don't really understand what should be changed. If I try to put `print('Hello world')` in the for loop everything is working.

p.s. If you have an example of how to make the output look more beautiful you are welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The only subscripion in your looks seams to be prediction[0][0]. Can you tell what Python package model.predict comes from? My guess is PyTorch.

Comment: @JanPedersen it is a TensorFlow

Comment: Ok, I have no real knowledge with TensorFlow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
i = 1
for item in os.listdir(DATADIR):
    prediction = model.predict([prepare(r'MY_DIR\manual_testing\{}.jpg'.format(i))])
    img = mpimg.imread(r'MY_DIR\manual_testing\{}.jpg'.format(i))
    imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()

    print(CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0][0])])
    i += 1
```